# How to give "yes" while running an application via batchfile?

Tags: batch-file

I want to run an application via batch file.
it asks me to enter yes for 6 times.
how I can do that in batch file.

Comment: Even in the most vivid of imaginations, the `C` tag on this question is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@echo off
(echo yes&echo yes&echo yes&echo yes&echo yes&echo yes) >temp
yourprogram.exe <temp & del temp
```